# Android - Scan barcode/QR to open file without Internet access

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code

This is mostly a question of design. I would like to label physical items with barcodes or QR codes and scan them to open a local file that corresponds to that item. Here is my specific situation for context:

The reason I need this is so that technicians can scan equipment with an Android phone camera to view past calibration logs and make edits in Google Sheets. The catch is that I want them to be able to do this without internet access. I know that I can make a QR code open a file locally but the file paths differ from phone to phone and I don't want to make barcodes that will be useless next year.

Some of the many options I've considered include:

1.) App that [decodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340875/integrate-zxing-qr-code-scanner-without-installing-barcode-scanner) and [stores](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162) QR/barcode as input variable to get file path by [traversing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866619/traverse-through-each-file-in-sd-card-using-phonegap-file-api) the directory and comparing the input to local file names (on SD card) with if statements. Then opens file with [intents](http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-file-with-default-application-using-intents).

- Difficult to store barcode/QR code

2.) QR/barcode opens spreadsheet directly from specified URI

- Change in file path can render QR/barcodes useless

3.) QR/barcode URI opens app that opens spreadsheet

- One application needed per spreadsheet - impractical

Any recommendations would be very helpful. I think the first option seems achievable but I don't know how to store the scanned codes. Perhaps someone with experience is familiar with another way.

Comment: Note: I am not a developer (I am an engineer) so there may be incorrect lexicon in my post. If so, please advise me for editing.

Answer (score 0):

It may be advisable to look at the concept of Arrays. They are versatile enough that you can load an inventory from storage, and access it in the same manner as you would a database. You can find out more [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html)

Once you have an array set up, all you need is code to recognise the QR code, which will return a product number/ID, which you can use to access the product in the array. You might consider a portable database that uses the QR number as the primary key. In order to do this, you may have to use SQLlite to store the entire database on the device. You can read more about that [here.](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/using-sqlite-on-android/232900584)

Edit: You'll need to change your existing scanner to recognise and return an **integer** or a **string**, which you can then use as the parameter for locating the product in the database.